# Create Search Box Control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a search text box where I have a Text Box area plus the button. So far I achieve my expected layout:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SearchTextBox}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                          Width="200">
                            <TextBox Width="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                            <Button Width="50" Content="Browse"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then I created the Control:

```
static SearchTextBox()
 {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SearchTextBox)));             
 }

 TextBox txtFileName = null;

 public TextBox TxtFileName
 {
     get { return txtFileName; }
     set { txtFileName = value; }
 }
 Button btnBrowse = null;

 public Button BtnBrowse
 {
      get { return btnBrowse; }
     set { btnBrowse = value; }
 }
```

Now I would like to access this button and text box so I can define their name, content, etc individually.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using MVVM principles or do you just want to write logic in the code-behind? If you are using MVVM you just need to bind the textbox and button in the xaml and write a command for the button in your ViewModel. If you are writing in the codebehind, just name your textbox and button and you can access them directly by name in the code-behind

Comment: See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101975/Building-a-Search-Text-Box-Control-with-WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, you can simply use **UserControls** to create your custom control.

Here is the link to create a sample usercontrol.  Extend the control based on your requirement

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/

Comment: I'll try that way and give feedback

Answer (score 1):

Overide this method in your class. public virtual void OnApplyTemplate().
Then create and instantiate the controls that you need.
something along these lines:

GetTemplatechild will allow you to get any dependency objects that have been defined. Do give them a name (x:Name="foo").

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    DependencyObject ButtonControlInTemplate = GetTemplateChild("searchbutton");// set the name as the x:Name for the controls in your xaml.
    Button SearchButton = (Button)ButtonControlInTemplate;
    DependencyObject TextBoxInTemplate = GetTemplateChild("searchinputfield"); // set the name as the x:Name for the controls in your xaml.
    TextBox InputTextBox = (TextBox)TextBoxInTemplate; 
    base.OnApplyTemplate();


}
```

NB. its important to check for null, sometimes the template isn't applied properly.

Comment: I tried that and the 2 components are returning null

Comment: Is the style definately being applied to the control?

Comment: how can I confirm it?

Comment: To confirm it, does your control display correctly, with the textfield and the search button. Also I forgot to include the base call. I've edited the code to include it, that could be the reason for the null results try that out. add base.OnApplyTemplate();